# Elementary Number Theory: Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

If $\gcd(m,15)= \gcd(n,15)=1$, show that either $15|(m^4 + n^4)$ or $15|(m^4 - n^4)$.

I'm really stuck on this proof. This is what I know:

Since the $\gcd(m,15)= 1$ we can write it as $mx+15y=1$ where $x,y$ are integers. Also, since $\gcd(n,15)=1$ it can also be written as $nu + 15v = 1$ where $u,v$ are integers. I think I'm missing something but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

As $\phi(15)=8,a^8\equiv1\pmod{15}$ for $(15,a)=1$

$\implies15$ divides $a^8-b^8=?$ for $(15,a)=(15,b)=1$

We can prove something more:$15$ will actually divide $a^4-b^4$

as $\lambda(15)=4, a^4\equiv1\pmod{15}$ for $(a,15)=1$

Comment: I sort of understand your hint but I reached a point where I have $m^8 \equiv 1$ (mod 15) and $n^8 \equiv = 1$ (mod 15).  I'm confused on how to get $15|(m^4 + n^4)$.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions mean that $\;m,\,n\;$ aren't divisible by $\;3\;$ and neither by $\;5\;$ , yet $\;m^4\,,\,n^4\;$ are both $\;=1\pmod 3\;$ , whereas by Fermat's Little Theorem both $\;m^4,\,n^4=1\pmod 5\;$ ...